# Какое действие скрывается за запятой?

Tags: c

```
// reverse the number so that the 1's digit is first
    for (i = 0; i * 2 < *d_a - 1; i++) 
    {
        c = a[i], a[i] = a[*d_a - i - 1], a[*d_a - i - 1] = c;
    }
```

Наткнулся на такой код, и не понятно,почему всё написано специально в строчку и через запятую? Зачем так писать?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Язык С испокон веков поддерживает две парадигмы программирования: программирование на языке инструкций (statements) и программирование на языке выражений (expressions). Один и тот же код во многих случаях можно записать и на языке инструкций, и на языке выражений.

- На языке инструкций мы реализуем [дейкстровскую](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) концепцию *последовательного выполнения* путем простого последовательного перечисления инструкций. Концепция *ветвления* реализуется через инструкции `if` и `switch`. Концепция *итерирования* реализуется через `for`, `while` и т.п
- На языке выражений мы реализуем концепцию *последовательного выполнения* путем перечисления подвыражений с оператором "запятая" в качестве "разделителя". Концепция *ветвления* реализуется через оператор `?:`. Концепция *итерирования* не реализуется (разве что через рекурсию, которая требует обращения к языку инструкций). Операторы `&&` и `||` реализуют "гибридные" концепции *последовательного выполнения + ветвления*.

Так что это и есть ответ на вопрос о роли оператора "запятая" - это бинарный оператор, который обеспечивает последовательное изолированное вычисление двух подвыражений: сначала левого, а потом правого. При этом результатом всего выражения является результат *правого* операнда оператора "запятая". Последнее автоматически означает, что в выражении

```
<подвыражение_1>, <подвыражение_2>, ..., <подвыражение_N>
```

результаты подвыражений от 1-го до N-1-го игнорируются. Если эти подвыражения не имеют побочных эффектов, то они фактически "ничего не делают" вообще, ни на что не  влияют и могут быть спокойно удалены из кода.

Зачем оператор "запятая" применен в вашем примере - сказать трудно. Там никакой необходимости в применении именно оператора "запятая" не видно. Скорее всего это особенность стилистических предпочтений автора кода. Запись в одну строчку, как и запись одним выражением, обычно затрудняет пошаговую отладку кода.

---

Одно из [полу-]идиоматических чисто стилистических применений оператора "запятая" проистекает из его популярности в заголовках цикла `for`. Например, некий цикл может выглядеть так

```
int array[N];
...
int *ptr = array;
for (unsigned n = N; n > 0; --n, ++ptr)
  ...
```

Если по какой-то причине нам понадобится "досрочно" перейти к следующему элементу (или даже вообще перенести последнюю часть заголовка `for` внутрь тела цикла), то такой переход могут записывать именно через оператор "запятая", чтобы подчеркнуть тот факт, что это фактически вынесенная сюда часть заголовка цикла

```
for (unsigned n = N; n > 0; /* --n, ++ptr */)
{
  ...
  if (...)
    --n, ++ptr;
  ...
  --n, ++ptr;
}
```

Comment: _"Запись в одну строчку, как и запись одним выражением, обычно затрудняет пошаговую отладку кода"_ - это из какого года информация?

Answer (score 3):

Оператор запятая (только не надо путать с перечислением аргументов или объявлением переменных через запятую) предназначен для последовательного выполнения нескольких действий. В данном случае, скорее всего, он использовался для того, чтобы не ставить фигурные скобки (впрочем, их всё равно кто-то добавил). Ну либо просто для того, чтобы подчеркнуть целостность действия в этой строчке (своп двух переменных), а не разбивать его на 3 независимых оператора.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор «запятая» используется для связки нескольких выражений. Левая сторона оператора «запятая» всегда вычисляется как void (то есть не выдающее значения). Это означает, что значение выражения, находящегося с правой стороны, станет значением разделенного запятыми выражения. Например:

```
х = (у = 3, у + 1);
```

Об операторе «запятая» следует думать как об обычном слове «и» в нормальном русском языке, когда оно используется в выражении «сделай это, и это, и это».

http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/operator-zapyataya

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zs06xbxh.aspx

http://proguroki.ru/urok4/urok-4-8-operatsiya-zapyataya

Comment: А об операторе `&&` можно думать как об обычном слове «и» в нормальном русском языке?