# C++,оптимизация подобия функции strstr(const char*,const char*)

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Вот код:

```
using std::cout;
int CheckArray(const char* str, const char* str1, const size_t size_N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size_N; i++) {
        if (str[i] == str1[i]) {
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int mystrstr(const char* str, const char* str1) {//хотел зделать подобие strstr(const char*,const char*) только чтоб возращало номер с какого места идёт вхождение строки str1 в str
    const size_t str_size = strlen(str);//максимальный допустимый размер проверочной строки(для цикла)
    const size_t str1_size = strlen(str1);//размер строки которая подставляеться на проверку (str) на правильность в temp(тоесть temp == str1)
    char* temp = new char[str1_size];//временный массив для копирования части целевой строки и будущей проверки
    int count_up = 0;//счетчик для вставление в temp с последующим збрасыванием для сравнения новой части строки
    int i = 0;//счетчик для копирования str в temp
    for (int limit = str1_size; limit <= str_size; limit++) {//проверяем до конца строки
    //(потому что count_up будет завершать ниже приведенный цикл и копировать только target_size символов(первую часть) в temp)
        for (;count_up < str1_size; i++, count_up++) {//если count_up достигает target_size или i доходит до  max_size значит копирование части завершено
            temp[count_up] = str[i];//копируем часть строки в временный массив для проверки
        }
        if (CheckArray(temp, str1, str1_size) == 1) { // если проверка удалась
            delete[] temp;//чистим память
            return i - str1_size;//возращаем место вхождения строки str1 в str(если отсчитывать от нуля)
        }
        count_up = 0;//сбрасывание счетчика чтобы не заходить за пределы массива
        i -= str1_size - 1;//для того чтобы проверять часть строки смещяясь не на новую строку,а на один символ(ксатате фактически это сломало мне голову)
    }
    return -1;//сравнивание не удалось
}
```

Это мое подобие функции strstr() только оно показует место откуда начинаеться входимая строка(если отсчитывать с нуля).
Хочу узнать почему я говнокодер и как мне бы оптимизировать мой код,чтоб он работал быстрее и эфективней.

Comment: Не огорчайтесь. [Настоящие реализации](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strstr.c) намного сложнее

Comment: Даже толком не вникая в детали реализации, сразу же возникает нестерпимое жаление задать закономерный вопрос: зачем вам понадобился массив `temp` и зачем понадобилось это "копирование части строки в временный массив для проверки". Почему бы вам не выполнить эту "проверку" прямо на исходных оригинальных данных. Зачем их куда-то копировать в сторонку??? Откуда у вас возникла такая идея?

Comment: Также, что это за условие цикла такое, записанное "через запятую": `for (; i < max_size, count_up < target_size; i++, count_up++)` и что оно по-вашему проверяет?

Comment: @fvBn: Не понимаю вопроса о "проверяли". Цель вашего исходного вопроса - *оптимизация*, как вы ясно сказали и в заголовке, и в тексте вопроса. Поэтому неудивительно, что люди будут вам указывать на очевидные примеры грубой *неоптимальности* вашего кода. (Не говоря уже о том, что `temp` в вашем коде - очевидная утечка памяти. Утечки памяти куда записывать? В ошибки или в неоптимальности?)

Comment: @AnT я не смог НЕ скопировать,поскольку,не знаю как это воплотить(реализовать),я не профессионал в C++,но учу при этом его долго

Comment: Условие цикла на которое вы жалуетесь - это цикл который позволяет скопировать ЧАСТЬ от всей строки во временный массив для дальнейшей проверки

Comment: @fvBn: Условие `i < max_size, count_up < target_size` эквивалентно просто условию `count_up < target_size`. То есть первая часть - `i < max_size` - просто игнорируется и ничего не делает. (Почитайте о том, что такое оператор "запятая": https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917702/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9). Поэтому и возникает вопрос: зачем вы туда вписали это `i < max_size` и какие надежды возлагали на это сравнение.

Comment: Спасибо уже исправил,вы помогли,а сколько лет вы отдали за эти знания? Просто я посмотрел вы прямо профессионал в этой сфере,если честно,я вас боюсь

Comment: И как я понял это всё из-за иерархии выполнения,поэтому условие перед запятой не будет даже читаться,правильно понимаю?

Comment: @fvBn, `профессионал в этой сфере,если честно,я вас боюсь` - устами Ant'а глаголет истина, это факт :) А по сути кода, много strlen(), и это все ест время CPU, ещё он возвращает size_t, а не int

Comment: Современные быстрые оптимизации для работы со строками это SSE реализации, посмотрите libc, как там организованно. Хотя, вот простой пример https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse4-strstr

Comment: Хорошо,но я просто хотел посмотреть насколько я говнокодер