# Отличие if else от ()?:

Tags: c, if

Можете мне объяснить: Чем отличается `if` `else` от `if(...)?...:...`.
Как по мне делают они одно и тоже, но препод твердит, что первый вариант это мягко говоря - плохой код.

Comment: Вы про тернарную операцию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F? Это просто короче, можно использовать внутри выражений.

Comment: Что такое `if(...)?...:...`??? О чем речь вообще?

Comment: Плохой - смотря в каком случае. Иногда код короче с `if else`, иногда с `? :`.

Comment: Это из серии "что вкуснее - шашлык или мороженое". Если верить описанной вами настойчивости преподавателя, он еще не вышел из детского возраста и навязывает всем любовь к сладкому :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, что под конструкцией

```
f(...)?...:...
```

вы имеете в виду условный оператор

```
logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

результатом которого является вычисление значения выражения.

Если значения логического выражения `logical-OR-expression`  является значение, отличное от нуля, то значением всего выражения будет значение выражения `expression`, стоящего после знака `?`. В противном случае значением всего выражения будет значения выражения `conditional-expression`, стоящего после знака `:`.

То есть как и любое другое выражение данный условный оператор можно использовать в выражениях.

Что касается предложения `if-else`, то это предложение языка C, которое нельзя использовать в выражениях.

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную программу, написанную на C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    srand( ( unsigned )time( NULL ) );

    int x = rand() % MAX_VALUE;

    printf( "%d is %s\n", x, x % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd" );

    if ( x % 2 == 0 )
    {
        printf( "%d is %s\n", x, "even" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d is %s\n", x, "odd" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В программе генерируется случайное число `x` в интервале [0, MAX_VALUE), то есть от 0 до 100 (исключительно).

```
int x = rand() % MAX_VALUE;
```

Затем проверяется, является ли это число четным или нечетным и соответствующее сообщение выводится на консоль. Данная проверка и вывод сообщения выполняется двумя способами.

В первом случае в функции вывода `printf` используется условный оператор в качестве выражения, задающего третий аргумент

```
printf( "%d is %s\n", x, x % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd" );
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Во втором случае используется предложение `if-else` и соответственно два вызова `printf` в зависимости от значения условия в if.

```
if ( x % 2 == 0 )
{
    printf( "%d is %s\n", x, "even" );
}
else
{
    printf( "%d is %s\n", x, "odd" );
}
```

Причем в каждое вложенное предложение после `if` или `else` вы могли бы вставить другие предложения, так как в качестве вложенного предложения можно использовать составное предложение.

Например, вышепоказанное if-else предложение вы могли бы написать как

```
if ( x % 2 == 0 )
{
    printf( "%d is ", x );
    printf( "%s\n", "even" );
}
else
{
    printf( "%d is ", x );
    printf( "%s\n", "odd" );
}
```

В общем случае вы не можете делать тоже самое с условным оператором, так как это выражение, состоящее из трех подвыражений, вычисляемых определенным образом. Например, вы не можете включить предложение цикла. Единственное исключение - это предложения-выражений, как указанный вызов `printf`, который можно использовать также в выражениях.

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть, к примеру, как

```
80 is even
80 is even
```

Классический пример использования условного оператора в C - это написание макроса для вычисления максимального или минимального значения из двух выражений. Например,

```
#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

В C++ имеется соответствующая стандартная шаблонная функция `std::max`, объявленная в заголовке `<algorithm>`, тело которой состоит всего лишь из одного предложения `return` с выражением, представляющим собой выражение с условным оператором

```
template <class T> 
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b )
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}
```

Comment: "Вы не можете делать тоже самое с условным оператором" - где тут ошибка: https://ideone.com/sBkuKU ?

Comment: @Harry Здесь нет никакой ошибки. В этом предложении с условным оператором ( x % 2 == 0 )
            ? (printf( "%d is ", x ), printf( "%s\n", "even" ))
            : (printf( "%d is ", x ), printf( "%s\n", "odd" ));
    } используются подвыражения с оператором запятая. Выражения могут быть сколь угодно сложными и состоять из многочисленных подвыражений. Просто в моем примере в предложении if-else используются предложения-выражения, а в общем случае могут использоваться, например, циклы.

Comment: @Harry Я подправил ответ, чтобы было более ясно, о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 3):

`if` - это *инструкция* языка (statement). Оператор `?:` - это *оператор* в выражении. Это сущности совершенно разной природы, ничего общего между собой не имеющие.

Операторы используются в выражениях и их операндами являются другие выражения (подвыражения). Инструкции не могут использоваться в выражениях.

(См. также [Какое действие скрывается за запятой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917702/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9/917740#917740))